# MJPEG stream without boundaries

Tags: node.js, camera, ffmpeg, stream, mjpeg

I'm working on mjpeg streaming proxy for MJPEG cameras and I have trouble with one strange stream: `http://24.39.90.86:8001` Can someone help me how to find a boundaries in this stream? Common mjpeg stream usually contains eg. "--myboundary" but there are no headers in that stream. Thanks for any help.
J.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer myself - it's a "raw" stream of JPEGs: http://www.videotechnology.com/jpeg/jpeg_format.html